# How to compute an exponent in matlab without getting inf?

Tags: matlab, numeric, numerical

The title says it all: I want to calculate an exponent in matlab with big numbers, but I get overflow and it just returns infinity.

```
>> 100^1000

ans =

   Inf
```

Last time I checked, 100^1000 is decidedly smaller than infinity :)

Answer (score 6):

As Daniel has already pointed out, it's too big a number to be even outputted by MATLAB itself. This number is obtained with [**`realmax`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/realmax.html) for different datatypes. As an alternative to represent/use such huge numbers, you can use the corresponding `mantissa` and `exponent` with `base-10 representation` instead, which is the usual MATLAB representation. The function to get those two is listed here -

```
function [mantissa, base10_exponent] = base10_mantissa_exponent(base,exponent)

act_exp = exponent*log10(abs(base));
base10_exponent = floor(act_exp);
mantissa = power(10,act_exp - base10_exponent);

if rem(exponent,2)==1 && sign(base)==-1
    mantissa = -mantissa;
end

return;
```

Few example runs and comparisons with actual MATLAB runs for validation are listed next.

**Ex #1**

```
base = -125.343;
exponent = 101;
usual_approach = base^exponent
[mantissa, base10_exponent] = base10_mantissa_exponent(base,exponent)
```

Output -

```
usual_approach =
 -8.0930e+211
mantissa =
   -8.0930
base10_exponent =
   211
```

**Ex #2 (problem discussed in the question)**

```
base = 100;
exponent = 1000;
```

Output -

```
usual_approach =
   Inf
mantissa =
     1
base10_exponent =
        2000
```

Answer (score 5):

Working with 64bit floating point arithmetic, `100^1000` is `inf` because it is larger than the largest possible value. If the symbolic math toolbox is available, use `vpa` or `sym` to work with large numbers:

```
sym('100^1000')
```

or

```
vpa('100^1000')
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with large numbers there is also the class [High Precision Float](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class), with which the result can be achieved by writing

```
a = hpf(100);
b = hpf(1000);
c = a^b;
```

which gives `c = 1.e2000`. A call to `struct(c)` provides informations on how the number is internally stored.

```
struct(c)

ans = 

NumberOfDigits: [64 4]
   DecimalBase: 4
          Base: 10000
       Numeric: 0
          Sign: 1
      Exponent: 2001
        Migits: [1000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```